# Fitting a distribution to data: how to penalize "bad" parameter estimates?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm using using [scipy's least-squares optimization](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) to fit an [exponentially-modified gaussian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution) to a set of reaction time measurements. In general, it works well, but sometimes, the optimization goes off the rails and chooses a crazy value for a parameter -- the resulting plot clearly doesn't fit the data very well. In general, it looks like the problems arise from floating-point precision errors -- we head off into 0 or inf or nan-land.

I'm thinking of doing two things:

- Using the parameters to simultaneously fit a CDF and PDF to the data; I have formulas for both. (I'm using a kernel density estimate to approximate the PDF from the data.)
- Somehow taking into account the distance from the initial parameter estimates (generated by the method of moments approach on the wikipedia page). Those estimates are far from perfect, but are pretty good and seem to steer clear of "exploding floating point" problems.

Combining the PDF and CDF fits sounds pretty straightforward; the scales of the error will even be generally the same. But getting the initial parameter fits in there: I'm not quite sure if it's even a good idea -- but if it is:

- What would I do about the difference in scale? Should I normalize the parameter "error" to a percent error?
- Is there a reasonable way to decide on a relative weight between the data estimation error and parameter "error"?

Are these even the right questions to be asking? Are there generally-regarded "correct" answers, or is "try some stuff until you find something that seems to work" a good approach?

#### One example dataset

As requested, here's a dataset for which this process isn't working very well. I know there are only a few samples and that the data don't fit the distribution well; I'm still hoping against hope that I can get a "reasonable-looking" result from optimization.

```
array([ 450.,  560.,  692.,  730.,  758.,  723.,  486.,  596.,  716.,
        695.,  757.,  522.,  535.,  419.,  478.,  666.,  637.,  569.,
        859.,  883.,  551.,  652.,  378.,  801.,  718.,  479.,  544.])
```

#### MLE Update

I had a bunch of problems getting my MLE estimate to converge to a "reasonable" value, until I discovered this: If X contains at least one nan, `np.sum(X) == nan` when X is a numpy array but *not* when X is a pandas Series. So the sum of the log-likelihood was doing stupid things when the parameters started to go out of bounds.

Added a `np.asarray()` call and everything is great!

Comment: How clean looking is the data if plotted without the fit?  If the data does not seem to fit the modified Gaussian well in the first place you may be trying to fit a round peg into a square hole.

Comment: Sometimes not that well, sometimes pretty well. There isn't a super clear pattern to "ah yeah it really shouldn't fit here"

Comment: the parameters of gaussian distribution could be estimated directly from the datas using means, variance and skews. Have you tried this way?

Comment: Yes, that's the method of moments approach I mention in the OP. It yields a pretty good estimate, but optimization clearly improves it (as measured by plotting compared to a histogram/kde of the data) for most of my datasets.

Comment: Have you tried weighting by the y-values in the PDF?  E.g. http://scipy-central.org/item/28/2/fitting-a-gaussian-to-noisy-data-points  It should help, at any rate, though it's not a solution for the CDF

Comment: For what it's worth: simultaneously fitting the PDF and CDF does not seem to be a magic bullet.

Comment: Just provided a MLE solution for you. The example is simple, but you should probably be using a different optimizer in your real stuff as you want to constrain some of your parameter in `(0, +inf)`. Other than that, nothing is too magic. To improve speed you can: 1, use a different optimizer; 2, hardcode your own `erfc`; 3, tune `eg_pdf` a little bit. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood for mathematical details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been a comment but I run out of space.

I think a Maximum Likelihood fit is probably the most appropriate approach here. ML method is already implemented for many distributions in `scipy.stats`. For example, you can find the MLE of normal distribution by calling `scipy.stats.norm.fit` and find the MLE of exponential distribution in a similar way. Combining these two resulting MLE parameters should give you a pretty good starting parameter for Ex-Gaussian ML fit. In fact I would imaging most of your data is quite nicely Normally distributed. If that is the case, the ML parameter estimates for Normal distribution alone should give you a pretty good starting parameter.

Since Ex-Gaussian only has 3 parameters, I don't think a ML fit will be hard at all. If you could provide a dataset for which your current method doesn't work well, it will be easier to show a real example.

Alright, here you go:

```
>>> import scipy.special as sse
>>> import scipy.stats as sss
>>> import scipy.optimize as so
>>> from numpy import *

>>> def eg_pdf(p, x): #defines the PDF
    m=p[0]
    s=p[1]
    l=p[2]
    return 0.5*l*exp(0.5*l*(2*m+l*s*s-2*x))*sse.erfc((m+l*s*s-x)/(sqrt(2)*s))

>>> xo=array([ 450.,  560.,  692.,  730.,  758.,  723.,  486.,  596.,  716.,
        695.,  757.,  522.,  535.,  419.,  478.,  666.,  637.,  569.,
        859.,  883.,  551.,  652.,  378.,  801.,  718.,  479.,  544.])

>>> sss.norm.fit(xo) #get the starting parameter vector form the normal MLE
(624.22222222222217, 132.23977474531389)

>>> def llh(p, f, x): #defines the negative log-likelihood function
    return -sum(log(f(p,x)))

>>> so.fmin(llh, array([624.22222222222217, 132.23977474531389, 1e-6]), (eg_pdf, xo)) #yeah, the data is not good
Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.
array([  6.14003407e+02,   1.31843250e+02,   9.79425845e-02])

>>> przt=so.fmin(llh, array([624.22222222222217, 132.23977474531389, 1e-6]), (eg_pdf, xo), maxfun=1000) #so, we increase the number of function call uplimit
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 170.195924
         Iterations: 376
         Function evaluations: 681

>>> llh(array([624.22222222222217, 132.23977474531389, 1e-6]), eg_pdf, xo)
400.02921290185645
>>> llh(przt, eg_pdf, xo) #quite an improvement over the initial guess
170.19592431051217
>>> przt
array([  6.14007039e+02,   1.31844654e+02,   9.78934519e-02])
```

The optimizer used here (`fmin`, or Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm) does not use any information from gradient and usually works much slower than the optimizer that does. It appears that the derivative of the negative log-likelihood function of Exponential Gaussian may be written in a close form easily. If so, optimizers that utilize gradient/derivative will be better and more efficient choice (such as `fmin_bfgs`).

The other thing to consider is parameter constrains. By definition, sigma and lambda has to be positive for Exponential Gaussian. You can use a constrained optimizer (such as `fmin_l_bfgs_b`). Alternatively, you can optimize for:

```
>>> def eg_pdf2(p, x): #defines the PDF
    m=p[0]
    s=exp(p[1])
    l=exp(p[2])
    return 0.5*l*exp(0.5*l*(2*m+l*s*s-2*x))*sse.erfc((m+l*s*s-x)/(sqrt(2)*s))
```

Due to the functional invariance property of MLE, the MLE of this function should be the same as same as the original `eg_pdf`. There are other transformation that you can use, besides `exp()`, to project `(-inf, +inf)` to `(0, +inf)`.

And you can also consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier.

Comment: Huh! Part of what's going on here is that your implementation of the PDF is working a lot better than mine; mine gets squirrely with large-ish (say, 0.1) values of lambda. I have some kind of floating point division problem (or something) that you don't have.

Comment: Huh! MLE is a nice trick. It took a few minutes to wrap my head around, but this should work better than minimizing squared error of my evaluated PDF. Any guidance on which optimizer I might choose?

Comment: AHA. I'd been using (1 - sse.erf(...)) as opposed to sse.erfc() which makes a difference at the boundaries. I'd thought it would be equivalent but I guess not ;)

Comment: Yeah `erfc()` and `erf()` are different. I was bitten once before as well. Just edited the answer for alternative optimizers. I think you can write the derivative in a close form. That will help a lot.

Comment: Writing the derivative is melting my mind somewhat. Would I consider x to be a constant in that case, and differentiate in terms of m, s, and l? And `llh` is the sum of a bunch of logs... ghhhaahgh? Sorry, my calculus is like 13 years old.

Comment: Yes, the derivative function is for the partial derivatives of the parameters (therefore `x` is considered as constant). The optimization process can be regarded as a searching in the parameter space for the vector that maximize the log-likelihood function GIVING a set of `x`. `llh` is the sum of log which I think is a good thing. The derivative is also the sum of a bunch of things (the derivative of PDF), each for   one observation in `x`. That may work out easily.

Comment: But you need to think about whether you need to improve the efficiency of the MLE process in the first place. Maybe it only accounts for a tiny proportion of your total execution time. If it is not the speed limiting factor then just stay with the derivative free optimizers. Or it takes years to generate the data and it doesn't matter whether it takes seconds or days to run your analysis. Always something to consider before trying to improve efficiency.

Comment: It's definitely running fast enough -- thanks! You've honestly gone above and beyond, here. My main challenge right now is that there are some datasets where the MLE optimization is converging to "silly" values while my PDF/CDF leastsq optimization is doing pretty well. They're all cases that don't fit the distro well, so I'm not shocked -- but even starting with what look like very good parameter estimates (PDF fits histogram of data) doesn't seem to help; it'll just go off the rails sometimes and I'm not quite sure how. But I can debug...

Comment: Hi Nate, check out this: http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/mathematical_optimization/ (Sorry if you already did). Watch out for float point overflows and whether any parameters becomes negative. If the latter is the case, you may want to consider that `eg_pdf2` alternative.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's floating-point precision problems; here's debugging from the early iters of llh:
`p: [862.8, 153.9, 0.2434], llh: 420.874333334`
`p: [876.7, 156.4, 0.2473], llh: 78.4056170211`
`p: [821.0, 158.8, 0.2512], llh: 18.8678560987`
`p: [793.2, 163.8, 0.2591], llh: nan`
So little changes in the parameters are making llh() explode, presumably because evaluating the function is exploding. Thanks for the link; I hadn't seen that yet!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42666/discussion-between-nate-and-ct-zhu)

Comment: Sorry for the chat link; I thought it would move the comment thread because that's what the link says it'll do :/ See the edited Q for the ultimate fix. And thanks a million for all your help.